# Extract Path up until the last occurrence of "\" in Batch

Tags: batch-file, path

The task is simple: Given Path: C:\Auto\proj Output: C:\Auto. i.e. Extract given path up until but not including the last occurrence of "\" in batch.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
set "givenpath=C:\Auto\proj"
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=\" %%a in ("%givenpath%") do set "givenpath=%%a\%%b"
echo %givenpath%
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "givenPath=C:\Auto\proj"

for %%f in (%givenPath%) do (
  set "parentPath=%%~dpf"
  set "parentPath=!parentPath:~0,-1!"
)

echo %parentPath%
```

Another option:

```
@echo off

setlocal

set "givenPath=C:\Auto\proj"
call :Dirname "%givenPath%"
goto :eof

:Dirname
set "parentPath=%~dp1"
set "parentPath=!parentPath:~0,-1!"
echo %parentPath%"
```

Or you could pass the path as a commandline argument:

```
@echo off

setlocal

set "parentPath=%~dp1"
set "parentPath=!parentPath:~0,-1!"
echo %parentPath%"
```

Comment: Whats: set "parentPath=%%~dpf"??

Comment: `%%f` (the loop variable) contains `%givenPath%`, i.e. `C:\Auto\proj`. `%%~dpf` is just the drive (`d`) and path `p` portion of that, i.e. ``C:\Auto\``. The string replacement in the next line removes the trailing backslash.

Comment: Because variable substitution works only with loop variables and commandline arguments. Yes.